# Have no idea how to imlpement Quicksort

Tags: c++, quicksort

I am trying to implement quicksort in this for just research. But i have no idea how quicksort works im looking at this algorithm but have no idea what or how to implement it right now im using bubble sort but how do i go ahead and implement quicksort?

```
# choose pivot
swap a[1,rand(1,n)]

# 2-way partition
k = 1
for i = 2:n, if a[i] < a[1], swap a[++k,i]
swap a[1,k]
→ invariant: a[1..k-1] < a[k] <= a[k+1..n]

# recursive sorts
sort a[1..k-1]
sort a[k+1,n]
```

This is my code below

```
int main()
{
srand(time(NULL));
    int length = 250000;
    double arr[length];
    for(int i = 0; i<length; ++i) arr[i] = rand();
   // mergeSort2(arr, arr+length-1);


        for(int i = 0; i < (length-1); i++)
    {
        for(int j = i+1; j < length; j++)
     {
           if( arr[i] > arr[j])
            {
               swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    ofstream ofs("input.txt");
    for(int i = 0; i<length; ++i) ofs << i << " " << arr[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Have you look at this first?
http://www.csanimated.com/animation.php?t=Quicksort

Comment: There is nothing wrong looking at the code right now. People usually forget the actual implementation in a matter of 5 seconds. What matter is understand the mechanism (how QS works).

Comment: Using Bubble Sort (or even thinking about), is not recommended. What is the trouble with your code anyway?

Answer (score 4):

This [animation](http://www.csanimated.com/animation.php?t=Quicksort) is really helpful.

The heart of quick sort (Dive and Conquer) is simply the following:

1. Pick an element as pivot

   - In practice ***most of the time*** we don't care which one. As you will see by proof, picking a pivot randomly (instead of front / end / mid) will minimize the possibility of running into the worst-case.
   - For test purpose, pick the middle guy is a good choice.
2. Partitions   (l = left, r = right)

   The goal is to partition your original array into two sets (virtually!!)

   S_left = { x in S - {pivot} :  x less than or equal to pivot }

   S_right = { x in S - {pivot} : x greater than or equal to pivot }

   To ease the notation:

   - a[l]....a[i-1] are less than or equal to a[i]
   - a[i+1]...a[r] are greater than or equal to a[i]
   - and hence, at the end, a[i] (the pivot element) should be in its proper place.

**Strategy**

There are two common ways to program QS, but in general QS takes three parameters (Array, low, high), where low is the left-end index of the array, and high is the right-end index of the array (could be 2,3, 5,10, not necessarily 0, length-1)

```
Initially
l = low-1
r = high

advances l when A[l] less than or equal to pivot
decrements r when A[r] is greater than or equal to pivot
swap A[l] and A[r]
repeat this process until l is greater than or equal to r, and swap (pivot, A[l])
Call QuickSort(A, left, l-1)
Call QuickSort(A, l+1, right)
```

I am giving you most of the implementation. 
Just work out with a small example (size 9 seems reasonable to me) on paper. Don't use rand until your implementation is correct.

Try this array:

> myArray = 9,6,2,5,11,4,20,1,3

I can write more tomorrow.